# Check hash of the package during pip install

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Is there a way to force `pip` check if md5 hash of a package matches the one from my `requirements` file?

So I could have a `requirements.txt` file like:

```
drf-compound-fields==0.2.0 md5=999168ac0303c4ea781da9cf47f841c1
```

Then if a hash is given for a package, `pip` would verify that hash of `*.tar.gz` (or whatever format is there) file matches it. If not -- it would refuse to install it.

Otherwise someone could break a developer's system and upload a malicious package version to PyPI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The peep package adds a hash to your requirement. So if you can check them after installing them the first time, then the hash will take care of checking that the package you expected to download is what pip (peep) is "really" downloading.

Your requirements.txt file will end up looking something like:

```
# sha256: L9XU_-gfdi3So-WEctaQoNu6N2Z3ZQYAOu4-16qor-8
drf-compound-fields==0.2.0
```

For more details: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/peep

Comment: PIP 8.0.0 changelog: > Include the functionality of peep into pip, allowing hashes to be baked into a requirements file and ensuring that the packages being downloaded match one of those hashes. This is an additional, opt-in security measure that, when used, removes the need to trust the repository.